# Capture names employees who login and logout cells are empty using for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to capture the name of the employee whos login and logout cells are empty and paste from cells range "A30". I used for loop and if condition to capture the employee whos login and logout cells are empty. By using the below code I get only the last person whos login and logout cells are empty.

How to capture all the employee's whos login and logout cells are empty.

```
For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 3).Value = "" And Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then

Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 1).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A35").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

Next
```

Comment: You are getting them all. Your problem is that you are copying them all to the same cell, so it only looks as if you are getting the last one. You need to increment the cell to which you are copying each time you copy.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, Can you please let me know how to increment it in above VBA code. I am a very beginner in VBA and coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to have a variable, which then gets incremented in your for loop.  Since you are pasting to a single cell each time, you can use Cells(x,y) rather than a range.  This makes it easier to use the variable.  Something like this should work for you:

```
Dim startOut As Integer
startOut = 30

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 3).Value = "" And Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then

        Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 1).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells(startOut, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        startOut = startOut + 1

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonathan, Now working fine, Is that possible copy another column which is shift details along with employee name like below:

Dim startOut As Integer
startOut = 30

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 3).Value = "" And Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then

        Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, 1,2).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells(startOut, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        startOut = startOut + 1

    End If

Next